# How to extend a feature's require conditions in Eiffel?

Tags: contract, eiffel

I have a class, which redefines the copy feature from `ANY`. I would like to add a new require condition, but I get this error:

```
Assertion in redeclaration uses just 'require' or 'ensure'. invalid precondition feature 'copy'
```

Code:

```
copy ( other : like Current )
require
    size_is_enough: Current.max_size >= other.count
do
    -- ...
end
```

Explanation:

This class contains an array, and I would like to check before copying, if the object has enough space for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preconditions in feature redeclarations can be weakened in Eiffel by using **require else** instead of **require** (for postconditions it would be **ensure then** instead of **ensure**). The new effective precondition will be a combination of the original one and the new one. For example, if there is a feature

```
foo
    require
        A
```

that is redeclared as

```
foo
    require else
        B
```

then the effective precondition will be `A or else B`. In other words, a precondition of a redeclaration is always weaker than of the original feature.

The same applies to the precondition of the feature `copy`: it can only become weaker. It means that you cannot check that the array size of the current object is larger than of the other one. The precondition of the redeclaration will only be checked  when the original precondition is not satisfied, i.e. when the type of the other object is different from the type of the current one. In other words, you are trying to strengthen the precondition and this is impossible.

One option is to use a different feature instead of `copy`, another is to resize storage of the current object if required. In both cases the precondition of the feature `copy` remains unchanged.